# String not receiving new value is always (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, string, null

Weird thing is happening here.

```
NSString *string = [powerPickerVC.powerList objectAtIndex:selRow];
NSLog(@"powerPicker row = %@", string); //this returns me the string from powerList
repVC.selectedPower = string; //selectedPower doesn't receive the new value and returns (null)
NSLog(@"selectedPower = %@", repVC.selectedPower);
```

And repVC.selectedPower is always returning `(null)`!

Just before that piece of code, I have this:

```
selectedRowPower = [powerPickerVC.powerPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
repVC.selectedRowInObjectPicker = selectedRowPower;
NSLog(@"selectedRowInObjectPicker = %d", selectedRowPower);
```

And that works perfectly. `selectedRowInObjectPicker` is an NSInteger but if I'm able to set its value, why am I not being able to set `selectedPower`'s value?

Yes, the object is synthesized and everything...

Comment: Are you 100% sure that repVC object is not nil at that place? That's the most likely reason you get such output in console

Comment: Yeah, I've used another instance from repVC just a couple lines above that and it worked fine.

Comment: how have you declared your selectedPower property in the .h file?

Comment: This: `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedPower;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

High chance that `repVC` is `nil`. Try to add breakpoint there and see.

Comment: Turns out it actually was. I added an alloc and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a method called `-setSelectedPower:` by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Why should I? It's a public string that I just want to access from another class. I mean, should I?

Comment: It's a property. It must be backed by a method. Presumably you've `@synthesize`d one. I ask because if you've added a method called `-setSelectedPower:` it gets called instead of the synthesized setter.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [NSString stringWithString: ] to initialize strings.

In your case,

repVC.selectedPower = [[NSString stringWithString:string];

And ensure the receiver is a properly declared NSString as intended.

Comment: what difference stringWithString call will make (assuming selectedPower property is declared correctly)?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already. Still returns me `selectedPower = (null)` in the debugger console. My NSString is declared. `NSString *selectedPower;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedPower;` plus the synthesize.